# How to list names of views in Plone 4 for a specific interface?

Tags: interface, components, plone, adapter, zope

Is there any simple way in zope component system to list all views (and their names), which were registered for specific interface (eg IMyInterface):

```xml
<browser:page
  name="content-item-plain"
  for=".interfaces.IMyInterface"
  class=".content_item.MyView"
  permission="zope2.View"
  layer="my.model.browser.interfaces.IMyModelLayer"
  template="templates/content_item_plain.pt"
/>
```

```python
class MyView(BrowserView):
    implements(ISomeInterface)
```

Or, even better, those, which implement certain interface (ISomeInterface)?

The result should be list/tuple of classes (MyView, MyView1, ...) and/or names ("content-item-plain", ...).

There is no problem to add classImplements/classProvides to the MyView class, if it helps.

Many things tried so far. The nearest is this:

```python
from zope.component import getGlobalSiteManager
gsm = getGlobalSiteManager()
gsm.adapters.lookupAll((IMyInterface, IMyModelLayer), provided=Interface))
```

but it gives too many results and changing `provided` to something more specific makes it return empty tuple.

With results it should be possible to lookup view class attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Get the list:

http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/browserviews.html#listing-available-views

And filter it out in a way you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have no choice but accept it, because now it seems to me that there is no "magic" method to find those views without alittle bit of further filtering. In addition to what is said in the docs, I can use my layer to constraint the number of views: registration.getViews(IMyLayer) and then filter.